# Convert print statements to log statements using a custom mapping

Tags: vimrc, neovim, filetype-python, python

I want to write or find a plugin that helps me convert print statements to log statements in Python 3.

Consider a situation:
I am writing some code, I want to add a feature based around some API, I quickly write a couple lines of code and add a bunch of print statements here and there that help me in understanding what the current state of the program is.

```
print("API response", response)
print(val1, val2)
print("I am a string with no variables")
print(f"I am an f-string so I will have {curly} {variables} here and there")
print(traceback.format_exc())
```

I want to be able to convert all these to log statements:

```
log.info(f"API response {response}")
log.info(f"{val1} {val2}"4)
log.info("I am a string with no variables")
log.info(f"I am an f-string so I will have {curly} {variables} here and there")
log.error(f"{traceback.format_exc()}")
```

In case of `f-strings`, it is a simple find and replace, but in all other cases, there's a lot of hassle around converting the print statement to a proper format before I can log it.

So far, I have written some custom mappings which use the surround.vim plugin:

```
"wrap value in bracket with f-string
nmap <leader>w ysib"ysi"}F"if<Esc>
"change print to log.info
nmap <leader>y csflog.info<Esc><leader>w
nmap <leader>wt _ys$}ysa}"If<Esc>_ys$)Ilog.error<Esc>
"maybe add map for direct writing the whole statement?
nmap <leader>yt Ilog.error(f"{traceback.format_exc()}")<Esc>
```

But they are very limited in usage

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This turns out to be difficult even with a macro, lots of edge-cases to consider. Obviously converting a general form into an f-string would solve the issue; you could do the print -> log.whatever afterwards.

Comment: I think it would be far easier to achieve what you want in `Python` than in `vim`. Simply add a new function to take in args like `...(*args)`, and then call `logs.info(" ".join(args))`. And maybe a second function to call `logs.error(" ".join(args))`. Once you have those functions, then use `vim` to (e.g.) `:%s/\<print(/print_log(/c`

Comment: thanks, @jalanb, I have posted a solution to this question. which is similar to your approach, but depends completely on Vim with no additional steps other than a substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A substitution like this works for all scenarios:

`%s/print(\(.*\))/log.info(" ".join([\1]))/`

- Grab everything within print brackets `(.*)` using regex
- replace the match with a `join` statement surrounding the match
- replace the `print` with `log.info` (or whatever is required)

Here is the test script if anyone wants to try it for themselves:

```py
import logging, traceback

logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', level=logging.DEBUG)

response = 'resp'
val1 = val2 = '1'

curly = "CURLY"
variables = "VARIABLES"

print("API response", response)

print(val1, val2)

print("I am a string with no variables")

print(f"I am an f-string so I will have {curly} {variables} here and there")

try:
    test
except:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Note: I found the solution [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/mrjld6/i_want_to_write_or_find_a_plugin_that_helps_me/gun8rko?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).
I also documented the question & answer in this [issue](https://github.com/ayushxx7/dotfiles/issues/2) & [PR](https://github.com/ayushxx7/dotfiles/pull/3).

Thanks for your response [@janand](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/182/jalanb) & [@Ben Knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble)