# Replace interpolated variables in Python string with positional formatting strings

Tags: regular-expression, filetype-python

How do I, with one regex, transform:

```
logger.info(f"Foo {alpha}")
logger.info(f"Foo {alpha} bar {beta}")
logger.info(f"Foo {alpha} bar {beta} baz {gamma}")
```

Into:

```
logger.info("Foo %s", alpha)
logger.info(f"Foo %s bar %s", alpha, beta)
logger.info(f"Foo %s bar %s baz %s", alpha, beta, gamma)
```

Background:

Idiomatically, log strings in Python should be written using "percent formatting", similar to formatting strings in c using `printf`, e.g.

```
o = { "lemurian": "lemurs" }
p = "are leaping"
logger.info("Something something %s %s", o, p)
```

Which outputs "Something something { "lemurian": "lemurs" } are leaping".

However, I have written lots of log messages with directly interpolated values, e.g.

```
o = { "lemurian": "lemurs" }
p = "are leaping"
logger.info("Something something {o} {p}")
```

Which outputs the same as above. I can change things by hand, but it's a pain. :D

Comment: If your python supports f-strings, it's a vastly easier problem to simply add `f` to the beginning of strings (though still not error-free)

Comment: I suspect this is related and may help: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/30981/convert-print-statements-to-log-statements-using-a-custom-mapping

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I'm trying to get rid of the f-strings. :)

Comment: Yeah, on second thought, that post may not be too helpful.

Comment: Why "one regex" (which I assume means "one substitution")? If this is just about getting the job done, I should think that one macro, one command (or series of commands) or even one function would be acceptable, no? Basically, "one operation"...

Comment: @BLayer curiosity, mostly. I want to know if there's a way to do it inside of a single `%s/.../.../`

Comment: @KitPeters Ah. No, I don't think there is, particularly due to the variable nature of it. Needs multiple steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a macro that does the transformation for a single `{}` that uses surround.vim:

```
let @q = "0f{ca}%s\<esc>f)i, \<esc>pds{"
```

(You can also record this by hand.)

Now, unfortunately, running this once for each `{}` group is harder. You could do it manually, of course, with `/{`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`n@qn@@n@@…`. You can get part of the way to automation with

```
:global/logger.info(f/normal! @q
```

which does a single step, and then you can iterate that with `@:` until there are no more brace-groups.